# Iterable[Try[(K, V)]] to Try[Map[K, V]]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a method `load` which is relatively expensive to call. In order to allow some kind of exception handling during loading it returns a `Try`. I need now an implementation for the `loadAll` method which basically delegates to `load` for each of the given keys. Here is my first approach, however I don't know if this is best practices with respect to the work with `Try`. Is there a better way to achieve the following?

```
def load(key: K): Try[V] // very expensive

def loadAll(keys: Traversable[K]): Try[Map[K, V]] = {

  // remove duplicate keys
  val ukeys = Set.empty ++ keys

  val result: Iterable[Try[(K, V)]] = ukeys map { key =>
    load(key) match {
      case Success(value)     => Success(key, value)
      case Failure(exception) => Failure(exception)
    }
  }

  Try(result.map { _.get }.toMap)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-liner in vanilla Scala (assuming you've already got `Try` in scope):

```
def loadAll(keys: Traversable[K]) = Try{ keys.toSet.map((k: K) => (k,load(k).get)).toMap }
```

Comment: Thank! It should just be mapped to a `Tuple[K,V]` as `(k,load(k).get)`. Am I right that this iterates 3 times over keys (once for `toSet`, `map` and `toMap`)?

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt - I've adjusted the answer to return a tuple.  This does iterate three times over the keys; if `load` is expensive then you don't care as `load` dominates all the other fiddling.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using a fold to iterate over the keys, and a for comprehension to combine the `Try` instances:

```
def toSet(keys: Traversable[K]): Try[Map[K, V]] = {
  keys.toSet.foldLeft( Try( Map.empty[K, V] ) ){ case (tryMap, key) => 
    for ( m <- tryMap; v <- load( key ) ) yield m.updated( key, v )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Works, but I had to change it slightly since `distinct` seems not to be available on `Traversable`

Comment: Fixed (replaced `distinct` with `toSet`).

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in a scalaz solution, this is a general operation, available via `Traversable` functors, called [`sequence`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L81). Needed instances for `Try` reside in [scalaz-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/blob/master/scala210/main/scala/Try.scala). Here's how it might look like:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._, scalaz.contrib.std.utilTry._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scalaz.contrib.std.utilTry._

scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> val result: Iterable[Try[(Int, String)]] = Iterable.empty
result: Iterable[scala.util.Try[(Int, String)]] = List()

scala> result.toList.sequence.map(_.toMap)
res0: scala.util.Try[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]] = Success(Map())
```

By the way, there's a paper ["The essence of the Iterator pattern"](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf), describing/deriving `traverse` (and `sequence`, as it's special case). There's a great summary of this paper by [Eric Torreborre](http://etorreborre.blogspot.de/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html) here.